# Mongoose How to await updating documents?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

im trying to figure out why my code isnt awaiting the update method in mongoose.

First I have tried to find the user

```
//Find user

 const user = await User.findOne({
    username,
    active: { $ne: false },
    accessBanExpires: { $lt: Date.now() },
  }).select('+password');

//Update the user property

 let newuser;

  if (remember) {
    if (!user.rememberAcct) {
      newuser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(user._id, {
        rememberAcct: true,
      });
      console.log('check: ', user.rememberAcct);
    }
  } else if (user.rememberAcct) {
    await user.updateOne({
      rememberAcct: false,
    });
  }
  console.log(user.rememberAcct, newuser);  //Here document always updating asyncrounously, but await seems not applying to update. newUser returns the user with old property
```

*document always updating asyncrounously, but await seems not applying to update. **newuser** returns the user with old property*

**Update:**

with options {returnDocument: 'after'} or {new: true} is still returning old document.

Refers: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findOneAndUpdate

What Im missing here?

```
newuser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(user._id, {
        rememberAcct: true,
      }, {returnDocument: 'after'});
```

Comment: Look at the first option [in the fine manual](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-findOneAndUpdate).

Comment: Hi with
{returnDocument: 'after' }
still doesnt return newest document. Mongoose 6.5.1

Answer (score 1):

In your snippet, there are 3 mistakes

1st

```
const user = await User.findOne({
  username,
  active: { $ne: false },
  accessBanExpires: { $lt: Date.now() },
}).select('+password') // <-- missing `rememberAcct` to select, without it `user.rememberAcct` will always be `undefined`
```

2nd

```
await user.updateOne({ // <-- this should be `User` not `user`
  rememberAcct: false, // <-- this filter will select a random user &  update query is missing
})
```

3rd :- Not using `user.save()` to update user.

here is final solution.

```
const user = await User.findOne(
  {
    username,
    active: { $ne: false },
    accessBanExpires: { $lt: Date.now() },
  },
  { password: 1, rememberAcct: 1 }
)

if (!user) throw new Error('user not found')

console.log('user.rememberAcct (before)', user.rememberAcct)

if (remember) {
  if (!user.rememberAcct) {
    user.rememberAcct = true
    await user.save()
  }
} else if (user.rememberAcct) {
  user.rememberAcct = false
  await user.save()
}

// NOTE: above `if/else` statements can be boiled down into single `if/else` statement, no need to check more than once. 
// I leave it you figure it out.

console.log('user.rememberAcct (after)', user.rememberAcct)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should either use `findByIdAndUpdate`, or pass a proper query:

```
// Either:
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  user._id,
  {
    rememberAcct: true
  },
  {
    returnDocument: 'after'
  }
);

// Or:
await User.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    _id : user._id,
  },
  {
    rememberAcct: true
  },
  {
    returnDocument: 'after'
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to place them into a try catches, let me know if the below works

this ads some error handling as well so you know why it may have failed.

```
 async function yourfunctionorrequest() {

  let password

    try {
      

        const user = await User.findOne({
            username,
            active: {
                $ne: false
            },
            accessBanExpires: {
                $lt: Date.now()
            },
        }, function (err, docs) {


            // set the specific item you were after to the variable
            password = docs.password
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)

    }
    let newuser;

    if (remember) {
        if (!user.rememberAcct) {

            try {
                newuser = await User.findOneAndUpdate(user._id, {
                    rememberAcct: true,
                });
                console.log('check: ', user.rememberAcct);

            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }


        } else if (user.rememberAcct) {

            try {
                await user.updateOne({
                    rememberAcct: false,
                });
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }

        }
        console.log(user.rememberAcct, newuser); //Here document always updating asyncrounously, but await seems not applying to update. newUser returns the user with old property




        console.log("error message", e)
    }


}
```

Comment: Hi there, it didnt catch any error.

Comment: can you share your code?